# How to compile Pattern with generic type <T>?

Tags: java

I don't understand why this code doesn't work:
edited(String regex and without  in Pattern)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Pattern<T> {

String regex;

public Pattern(String regex) {
    this.regex = regex;
}

public T getPattern(String text) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    // Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    return null;
}

}
```

I want to compile `Pattern` with generic `<T>` type.

Comment: `java.util.regex.Pattern.compile` takes a `String` argument, so it's not clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: with `String` it also doesnt work!

Comment: Well, that's probably due to your class name also being Pattern. Rename it.

Comment: It must work with String. Look up the Javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to rename your class. But you may also leave the name.

 To do so, you should just change your code:

```
public T getPattern(String text) {
  java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(regex);
  // Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Pattern<T> {

String regex;

public Pattern(String regex) {
    this.regex = regex;
}

public T getPattern(String text) {
    java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(regex);
    // Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    return null;
 }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, since compile requires that regex parameter is a String.

Comment: And the Pattern<T> class can not be cast to java.util.regex.Pattern.

Comment: You're right too, now it should compile. However as I said too, compile method accepts Strings and not generic T.

Answer (score 0):

rename your class, Pattern is already in your import `import java.util.regex.Pattern;`

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class MyPattern<T> {

        T regex;

        public MyPattern(T regex) {
            this.regex = regex;
        }

        public T getPattern(String text) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
            // Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: loool :D Thank you, am I blind? :D

Comment: `Pattern.compile()` certainly doesn't return value of type `MyPattern<T>`.